# creating outlook add-in for for outlook 2018

Tags: outlook, outlook-restapi

I am working on a project where I would create an extension in `outlook` that would allow you to see how many emails you received and sent for a certain email `(@edu.com)`. I also want to be able to see things like time received, if the person responded, and the average emails responded to for that particular email group. Any ideas on how I could accomplish this. From what I have seen so far, it looks like I should use the `Outlook Graph API` for. Any ideas or how to get started would be really nice!

Comment: Outlook 2018 does not exist AFAIK. It seems you mean Outlook 2019.

Comment: sorry mean outlook 2019 @VictorIvanidze

Answer (score 0):

Search for code examples, select the closest one and clone it.
After that try to change its functionality.